# Python Heroku Scheduler DB commit doesnt change values - DetachedInstanceError

Tags: python

I am using following code in the free heroku scheduler add-on to send emails to certain users. After the email was sent a value in the DB must be changed, to be more precise:

```
setattr(user, "stats_email_sent", True)
```

Somehow the `db_session.commit()` is executed but doesnt save the new value. Here is the code:

```
all_users = User.query.all()
for user in all_users:
    if user.stats_email_sent is False and user.number_of_rooms > 0:
        if date.today() <= user.end_offer_date and date.today() >= user.end_offer_date - relativedelta(days=10):
            print user.id, user.email, user.number_of_rooms, user.bezahlt
            if user.bezahlt is True:
                with app.app_context():
                    print "app context true", user.id, user.email, user.number_of_rooms, user.bezahlt
                    html = render_template('stats_email_once.html', usersname=user.username)
                    subject = u"Update"
                    setattr(user, "stats_email_sent", True)                    
                    #send_email(user.email, subject, html, None)
            else:
                with app.app_context():
                    print "app context false", user.id, user.email, user.number_of_rooms, user.bezahlt
                    html = render_template('stats_email_once.html', usersname=user.username)
                    subject = u"Update"
                    setattr(user, "stats_email_sent", True)                    
                    #send_email(user.email, subject, html, None)           

print "executing commit"
db_session.commit()
```

I tryed moving `db_session.commit()` right after `setattr` then it will work, but only for one user (for the first user).

```
setattr(user, "stats_email_sent", True)
db_session.commit()
```

And give me this in the logs:

```
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError: Instance <User at 0x7f5c04d462d0> is not bound to a Session; attribute refresh operation cannot proceed
```

I also found some topics on detaching an instance, but I don't need to detach here anything, or?

EDIT:

I tryed now also adding `db_session.expire_on_commit = False`. This sadly had no effect.

I also looked on the bulk updates, which also didn't worked.

I even tryed to ignore and `pass` the `DetachedInstanceError`.

I cant believe that updating multiple rows at once is such an issue. I am running out of ideas here. Any help is appriciated. It either has no effect or is run into `DetachedInstanceError`.

**EDIT**

I solved the issue, had yesterday a similar one. I assume the query and its variables were consumed, thats why it didnt worked.

To solve this I created a list `client_id_list = []` and appended all the ids of users which got the email and where the value needs to be changed.

Then I created a completely new query and all in all run the same code with the same logic, but the variables here were not consumed I guess? I wont answer the question again, because I am not sure whether this is true or not, here is the code which I appended to the code above which changes the values:

```
all_users_again = User.query.all()
for user in all_users_again:
    if user.id in client_id_list:
        setattr(user, "stats_email_sent", True) 
db_session.commit()
```

Comment: if you have solved the issue, post an answer and mark is as accepted so that future visitors can find it easily. Thanks!

Comment: My solution feels like a complex workaround and I can't explain it reliably. That is not a good answer.